# AES128 Encryption on Java, decryption on unix(openssl)?

Tags: java, unix, encryption, cryptography, aes

This is my first post here so apologies in advance if I am missing something or breaking any rules!

We are going to receive a AES128 encrypted file from a 3rd party. The 3rd party is using Java to encrypt the file. They are using AES/ECB/PKCSPadding for encryption.

We have to process the file on unix, and we are trying to use OpenSSL commands on unix to decrypt the file, however we are unable to do so. Source is not using any salt and using key as IV itself.

I have tried all options in OpenSSL however every time I am getting bad decrypt error. 
- Source is able to encrypt and decrypt at their end
- To test my commands, I encrypted and decrypted a file (on unix) and able to do so
- However whenver we exchange files and key, neither of us are able to decrypt the file

Things/Commands I have tried so far:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -in <> -out <> -nosalt -pass file:$HOME/keyfile
```

Changed the key into Hex and then tried below

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -K 'hex value' -iv 'hex value' -in <> -out <>
```

I am clueless at this stage as what could be going wrong. I am assuming with the use of AES the encryption/decryption should be independent of platform, but any pointes would be helpful if I am missing something!

Answer (score 0):

cryptography and algorithms like AES are independent of platform by nature.
When it comes to java it may be possible that the usage of big endian in java may be a problem.
Anyhow as an advice: never use your key as IV.